# URL for Omnifocus Context

Tags: launchpad, url, omnifocus

I would like to use a URL in Launch Pad Pro to open the "Home" context in OmniFocus whenever I get home.

I know to get to a perspective you use:

omnifocus:///perspective/PerspectiveName

But I've tried this for contexts, and it isn't working.

omnifocus:///context/Home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might not be exactly what you want, but it is possible to create a perspective with only the items in your home context, which you could have the url link to. That's the best solution I could find.

Comment: That's good enough for me Ethan. I hadn't thought of that. Thanks!